# How to place items horizontally below heading in Legend in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, legend

I'm working with ArcGis 10.2. I want to display a legend which is composed of Title ("Legend"), Heading ("Layer Name") and Items. I want the items (in this case three) to be horizontally disposed under the heading, so I set 3 as number of columns, but this way one column was assigned to the heading and two to the items (resulting in the third item to be in the same column of the heading or another item, as you can see in the picture below) while I want the heading to be above all three columns, each of which assigned to an item. How can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this stage (when your legend is fixed), you should convert your legend to graphics, ungroup the component and manually arrange them as you want (there are tools to align and distribute the graphics).